# Registry location with access for all users

Tags: registry, inno-setup

Is there a location in the Windows registry where all users (admin/not admin) are allowed to write and read values?

I'm using Inno Setup and while installing I give the choice to save userdata to `%appdata%` depending on the logged in user. While uninstalling I need to remove all the userdata written to the corresponding `%appdata` directories.

**My current approach is:**

Since the the installer always runs with administrator privileges, I write a value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE which indicates to use the `%appdata%` directory. Each user, who starts the application, will read this value and determine the users `%appdata%` directory.
For deleting the files later, the application writes the path to a given key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER. While uninstalling the application I wanted Inno to iterate through HKEY_USERS and read all given paths.
I now face the problem, that only active users are listed in HKEY_USERS, which would lead to the problem, that not all directories could be removed.

Since my approach will not work, I wanted to know where to save these paths where a (potentially not admin-) user is able to write a value and the setup is able to read these values.

Comment: What do you mean by *"only active users are listed in HKEY_USERS"*? What are non-active users?

Comment: Users who are not logged in. I created a local user which isn't listed in HKEY_USERS.

Comment: I surely have logged in with that user to add the corresponding registry key (and value)

Comment: If I'm logged in with the local user the corresponding key is listed in HKEY_USERS, otherwise it is not listed. Isn't this the correct behavior, to just load the hives of user who are logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no registry key writable by all users by default.

---

You can of course create one, if you want.

Check [`Permissions` parameter of `[Registry]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=Permissions).

---

But consider storing the information into a file in `ProgramData` folder ([`commonappdata` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=commonappdata) in Inno Setup). All `USERS` have permissions to create new folders and files in `ProgramData` folder. And when you create a file, you can grant all other users permissions to write to it (your installer can do that, again use [`Permissions` parameter of `[Files]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Permissions)).

Comment: I think storing it into `ProgrammData` isn't possible, because there may be users who are not allowed to write in these path. But I give the permissions parameter a try. Thank you!

Comment: All `USERS` have permissions to create new folders and files in `ProgramData` folder. And when you create a file, you can grant all other users permissions to write to it (your installer can do that, again use `Permissions` parameter of `[Files]` section).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Would also be a good solution. Since I want to hide this a little away from the user, the registry key with adjusted permissions is a good solution for me. Thank you again.